# Search for string within html link on webpage and download the linked file

Tags: linux, search, hyperlink, download, html

I am trying to write a linux script to search for a link on a web page and download the file from that link...

the webpage is:
http://ocram.github.io/picons/downloads.html

The link I am interested in is:
"hd.reflection-black.7z"

The original way I was doing this was using these commands..

```
lynx -dump -listonly http://ocram.github.io/picons/downloads.html &> output1.txt
cat output1.txt | grep "17" &> output2.txt
cut -b 1-6 --complement output2.txt &> output3.txt
wget -i output3.txt
```

I am hoping there is an easier way to search the webpage for the link "hd.reflection-black.7z" and save the linked file.

The files are stored on google drive which does not contain the filename in the url, hence the use of "17" in second line of code above..

Comment: I might be completely on the wrong track with the method above so if there is a beter & more efficient method to search a specific webpage for a hyperlink containing string "hd.reflection-black.7z" & downloading the linked file, it would be welcomed.

Comment: Do you want also the solution in python || perl || websockets and so On? Also, What about a solution working in a web browser (pure (x)html/ECMAscript )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@linuxnoob, if you to download the file (curl is more powerfull than wget):

```
curl -L --compressed `(curl --compressed "http://ocram.github.io/picons/downloads.html" 2> /dev/null | \
grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | \
sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' | \
grep hd.reflection-black.7z | \
sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d')` > hd.reflection-black.7z
```

without indentation, for your script:

```
curl -L --compressed `(curl --compressed "http://ocram.github.io/picons/downloads.html" 2> /dev/null | grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' | grep hd.reflection-black.7z | sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d')` > hd.reflection-black.7z 2>/dev/null
```

You can try it!

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
curl --compressed "http://ocram.github.io/picons/downloads.html" | \
grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | \
sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' | \
grep hd.reflection-black.7z | \
sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d'
```

Comment: That worked m8 & it looks like a winner, it prints this link to terminal window: `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_r6EZ4YgsqDdFdnbmQ4TDFReWc` Hou can I use wget to download the file and keep the orig filename `hd.reflection-black.7z`?  I tried `wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_r6EZ4YgsqDdFdnbmQ4TDFReWc"` but I get a strange filename instead of the hd.reflection-black.7z

Comment: @linuxnoob :A winner?No a googler! :) You can't use wget for this,curl print to standard output what it download,also notice the --compressed option which enable the accept encoding;wget does not support content encoding compression.Wget can't write to standard output it can only save to a file.For using wget you'll need 3 commands:the first one would download the page to a temporary file(wget).The 2nd is the one from my answer.You'll need to replace 'curl --[...] "http:/....html"' with 'cat temp_file'.The third one is for deleting the file. Do you want me to fully write it in an other answer?

Comment: He he :) your a lot better on google than me then m8 because I spent a good few hours looking for an answer before I posted.. Yes please m8, If you wouldn't mind I would appreciate it if you could add the lines of code to complete the download to current directory & with the correct filename (hd.reflection-black.7z), then I can dissect it to try understand the commands & your solution better..

Comment: @linuxnoob Ah Sorry, you want also to download `hd.reflection-black.7z`? I thought you don't wanted to use curl.

Comment: Yes m8, this task is a very small part of a large script, the end result of this particular piece of code will be to have the linked hd.reflection-black.7z saved locally to the working directory.. Also m8, i dont mind using curl, as long as we can keep the whole task in one piece of code within my master script

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to avoid using regular expressions since they tend to break in unexpected ways (e.g. the output is split in more than one line for some reason).

I suggest to use a scripting language like Ruby or Python, where higher level tools are available.
The following example is in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

main_url = ARGV[0] # 'http://ocram.github.io/picons/downloads.html'
filename = ARGV[1] # 'hd.reflection-black.7z'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(main_url))

url = doc.xpath("//a[text()='#{filename}']").first['href']
File.open(filename,'w+') do |file|
  open(url,'r' ) do |link|
  IO.copy_stream(link,file)
  end
end
```

Save it to a file like `fetcher.rb` and then you can use it with

```
ruby fetcher.rb http://ocram.github.io/picons/downloads.html hd.reflection-black.7z
```

To make it work you'll have to install Ruby and the Nokogiri library (both are available on most distro's repositories)

Comment: I could not get that to work m8 & there were way too many packages to install to make this rupy script work because I want to use it on multiple machines without all the baggage..  Thankyou for your input though..

Comment: @MarcoRighele : `sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g'` is especially written the case the code is obfuscated or other similar problems.